# Page title problem when setting ViewBag variable from razor section in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, title

Consider fallowing declaration in view

```
@section sideaction
{
  ...
  ViewBag.Title=Model.Title;
  ...
}
```

And in main layout i have this

```
<head>
    <title> @ViewBag.Title</title>
....
...
</head>
..
...
<body>
..
 @RenderSection("sideaction",required:false)
..
</body>
```

I am not getting title from view, i know that view will be processed before layout but i recognized that head section is processed before render section which is causing this problem. 
One more thing , ViewBag.Title=Model.Title is just an example , the real Model is IEnumrable object and i am iterating and finding proper title. I can iterate in controller to find title but there is already iteration in view. For big collections one iteration is more efficient.
 Any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't be better to pass the ViewBag.Title value through the controller?

Answer (score 3):

You **cannot** set a `ViewBag` value in a section.

Use this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = Model.Title;
}
```

directly in the view to set a title.

Comment: I am setting ViewBag value from section , it is possible! you can try if you want.

Comment: I think layout is parsed from top to bottom line by line, It see head section first then conditional section. View is processed first but when reflecting layout it ignores section definations.

Answer (score 0):

Even it doesn't work, notice that the code has to be like this:

```
@section sideaction
{
    @{
       ViewBag.Title = Model.Title;
    }
}
```

But as other people mentioned earlier, you can't do it this way inside a section. 
You should put it directly inside your view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = Model.Title;
}
```

By the way, if you persist to change title of a page from inside a section, use javaScript/jQuery, e.g:

```
@section sideaction
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            document.title = '@Model.Title';
        });
    </script>
}
```

Note: pay attention that it has to be '@Model.Title' (inside quotes).